# when i use php echo, why tag elements are closed automatically?

Tags: php, html, autocomplete, tags

I was trying to make this code as below.

**PHP code I wrote:**

```
$i = 1;
<div class="sampleNumberIndex">
  <p> 
    <h2> <?php echo $i; ?></h2> 
  </p> 
</div>
```

**Made code that I expected**

```
<div class="sampleNumberIndex"> 
  <p> 
    <h2> 1 </h2> 
  </p> 
</div>
```

**But php code made this.**

```
<div class="sampleNumberIndex"> 
  <p> </p>
    <h2> 1 </h2> 
  <p> </p>
</div>
```

I'm using chrome, what did make it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with PHP. It's just that html doesn't want you to wrap h2-tags in p-tags. You should rather use divs, regardless of what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking at `Inspect Element` section which repairs bad HTML codes. Real source codes are available at `View page source` section. Try `Ctrl + U` to view source code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question, but I suppose you're seeing the unexpected tags in the browser's DOM inspector. "Show Page Source" should show you the actual raw HTML your browser received.

Edit: what @AliN11 said

HTML infers tags when missing in content. In your case, the HTML browser knows that `h2` can't appear in the content of a `p` element, hence it adds the `</p>` end-element tag before `h2`. Then after the `h2` element, it encounters the `</p>` end-element tag, and inserts a `<p>` start-element tag before it, because none is open at the context position.

The first insertion - that for the `</p>` end-element tag - is part of the regular parsing rules for HTML; omitting `</p>` is allowed according to [the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/). But the second insertion - that for the `<p`> start-element tag - is not, and is an effect of HTML recovery (repair) kicking in.

I've explained HTML/SGML tag insertion in detail on the [project page of my SGML software](http://sgmljs.net/blog/blog1701.html) and the linked slides of a talk I gave about it last year.

Comment: Thanks for everyone trying to answer.